# How to pass data from Recyclerview onClickLister to other Activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to pass data from onclick recycler view main activity to other activity(exoplayer).
I created onimageclicklistener class and then I declared my onimageclicklistener in the adapter class. Then I implement that listener in main activity and implemented on image click method, now I am blank and do not know what do.
I will appreciate if someone helps.

interface class:

public interface OnImageClickListener

{

void onImageClick(String imageData);

}

adapter:

public class SongAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter  {

```
private Context context;
private List<Datum> datums;

//imagelistener define
private OnImageClickListener onImageClickListener;

//3rd argument is listener
public SongAdapter(Context context, List<Datum> datums, OnImageClickListener onImageClickListener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.datums = datums;
    this.onImageClickListener = onImageClickListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Datum datum = datums.get(position);

    Glide.with(context).load(datums.get(position).getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

    holder.title.setText(datum.getTitle());
    holder.artist.setText(datum.getArtist());
   // holder.duration.setText(datum.getDuration());
    holder.duration.setText(Integer.toString(datum.getDuration()));

    //imageview interface pass
    holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onImageClickListener.onImageClick(datum.getUrl());

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return datums.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView thumbnail;
    TextView title;
    TextView artist;
    TextView duration;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        artist = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
        duration = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
    }
}
```

}

Mainactivity:

```
//imageclick listener
@Override
public void onImageClick(String imageData) {

    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,exoplayer.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

I want to send data to exoplayer class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Answer (score 2):

### Using Intent Extras

```
@Override
public void onImageClick(String imageData) {

    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,exoplayer.class);
    intent.putExtra("YOUR_KEY_STRING", imageDate);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

And then from exoplayer Activity, you retrieve it in the `onCreate()` method as follows :

```
String imageData = getIntent().getStringExtra("YOUR_KEY_STRING");
```

### Using bundle

```
@Override
public void onImageClick(String imageData) {

    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,exoplayer.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("imageDataKey", imageData);  
    intent.putExtra("YOUR_BUNDLE_KEY", bundle);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

And then from your exoactivity you retrieve it as follows :

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
      Bundle bundle = getIntent().getStringExtra("YOUR_BUNDLE_KEY");    
      String imageData = bundle.getString("imageDataKey");
  }
```

Comment: holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onImageClickListener.onImageClick(datum.getUrl());  // this getUrl i want get there and send it to exoplayer class

Comment: Do you have in your MainActivity implements OnImageClickListener?

Comment: @ItsAk Have you solved this? In order to help other people if this helped you feel free to upvote and mark this as a correct answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Using intent we can send data

```
//imageclick listener
@Override
public void onImageClick(String imageData) {

    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,exoplayer.class);
    i.putExtra("data",imageData);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

Comment: but i want getUrl value on onclicklistener which i define in OnBindviewholder of adapter class.